# Thymeleaf Open new html file

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I didnt open new html file when onclick on button

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sign up Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Getir Library</h1>
<br>
<hr>
<form th:action="@{/Main}" method="post">
  <div class = "header">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <button type="submit" th:onclick="|window.location.href='/CustomerLogin'|" >Customer Login Page</button>
```

Also This is my Controller Class.

```html
@RequestMapping(value = "/CustomerLogin")
    String getCustomerLoginPage(){
        return "CustomerLogin";
    }
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is my html files in the javaspring project
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv7aq.png

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sign up Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to Getir Library</h1>
<br>
<hr>
<form th:action="@{/Main}" method="post">
  <div class = "header">
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <button type="button" th:onclick="|window.location.href='/CustomerLogin'|" >Customer Login Page</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

<Button type must button not submit and try again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).